# Errors after installing lodash in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I'm getting a MASSIVE stack of errors after installing lodash in my Angular 2 project. To test, I started a new project with the CLI: `ng new tester`, then I installed lodash with `npm install --save @types/lodash`. Then I ran `ng serve`, and I got the following:

```
ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,21): ']' expected.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,22): ';' expected.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,23): Declaration or statement expected.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,33): ']' expected.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,34): ')' expected.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,35): Declaration or statement expected.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,37): Declaration or statement expected.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19499,1): Declaration or statement expected.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (244,13): Duplicate identifier '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (248,19): Duplicate identifier '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (244,16): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (246,25): Cannot find name 'Partial'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (366,39): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (2083,24): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5636,44): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5643,44): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5650,44): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5657,44): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5690,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5699,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5706,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5713,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5722,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5729,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5736,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5745,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5752,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5759,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5768,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5775,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (5782,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,9): A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,10): Cannot find name 'P'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,15): Cannot find name 'keyof'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,21): Cannot find name 'T'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,26): A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,31): Cannot find name 'T'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,40): Cannot find name 'boolean'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11511,29): Cannot find name 'ConformsPredicateObject'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11522,42): Cannot find name 'ConformsPredicateObject'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (12762,29): Cannot find name 'object'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15452,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15461,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15494,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15503,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15538,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15547,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15580,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15589,12): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15622,22): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15629,22): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15662,24): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15669,24): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15685,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15694,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15704,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15714,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15724,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15734,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15744,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15754,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15789,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15797,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15804,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15836,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15844,21): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15851,21): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15914,21): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15914,37): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (15930,21): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16591,33): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16601,33): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16611,33): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16680,33): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16689,33): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16698,33): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16758,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16767,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16777,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16787,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16797,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16807,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16817,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16827,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16846,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16855,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16864,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16874,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16882,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16892,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16900,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16922,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16932,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16942,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16953,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16962,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16973,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (16982,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17139,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17147,21): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17154,21): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17170,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17179,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17188,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17197,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17207,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17215,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17225,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17233,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (17984,39): Cannot find name 'TemplateSettings'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18604,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18612,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18734,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18742,19): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18751,47): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18760,47): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18876,31): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18913,43): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18920,43): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18927,43): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18934,43): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18941,43): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18953,40): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18960,40): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18967,40): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18974,40): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18981,40): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (18993,39): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19000,39): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19007,39): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19014,39): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19021,39): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19032,39): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19072,53): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19079,58): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19086,58): Cannot find name 'Many'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19246,22): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19270,22): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19293,23): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19316,23): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19339,21): Cannot find namespace '_'.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19507,15): All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.
/Users/bradley/Work/test/tester2/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (19507,33): Cannot find name 'object'.
```

Please me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? If It's greater than 2.0.X ou should use "@types/lodash": "4.14.50"

Comment: Is there a reason I wouldn't just use the latest?

Comment: Some dependencies crash if you use the latest, because It's updated for TypeScript >= 2.4.x

Comment: Post your `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this error. Either [downgrade](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5592#issuecomment-288777878) the @types/lodash dependency to ts2.0,

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/lodash": "ts2.0",
}
```

or upgrade your typescript version to 2.2:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.58",
    "typescript": "^2.2.0",
  }
}
```

The further usage is `import * as _ from 'lodash';`